# How to get a cell value inside "quotation marks", using COUNTIF?

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, google-docs

I would like to use the following function:

=COUNTIF(B3:B400; "<=24/02/2012")

where 24/02/2012 should be replaced with a pointer to a specific cell. When I expand this function downwards, the pointer should increase likewise.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=COUNTIF(B3:B400; "<="&D3)`
here D3 is a cell with the date.

Comment: +1 ...and perhaps make the range reference absolute if formula is to be copied down, e.g. `=COUNTIF(B$3:B$400; "<="&D3)`